# Why does this condition not work?

Tags: php

I've noticed that the first condition does not work

```
if (empty($ss)) {
  echo "please write your search words";
}
```

but the second does

```
else if ($num < 1)   {
   echo  "not found any like ";
```

Full code:

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
$ss= $_POST["ss"];
$sql2=("SELECT * FROM student WHERE snum = $ss");
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($rs2);

if (empty($ss)) {
    echo "please write your search words";
}
else if ($num < 1 ) {
    echo  "not found any like ";
}else {
    $sql=("SELECT * FROM student WHERE snum = $ss ");
    $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
?>
<div id="name">
    <table align="center"  border="3" bgcolor="#FF6666">
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $data ["sname"]." "."نتيجة الطالب"; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="ahmed">
    <table width="50%" height="50" align="center" border="2px" bgcolor="#BCD5F8">
        <tr>
            <td width="18%"><strong>جيولوجي</strong></td>
            <td width="13%"><strong>تاريخ</strong></td>
            <td width="13%"><strong>رياضة</strong></td>
            <td width="14%"><strong>عربي</strong></td>
            <td width="12%"><strong>علوم</strong></td>
            <td width="30%"><strong>المادة</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td><strong>الدرجة النهائية</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <td><? echo $data['geo']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $data['snum']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $data['math']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $data['arab']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $data['history']; ?></td>
        <td><strong>درجات الطالب</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle">
                        <? $sum= $data['geo'] + $data['snum'] +
                            $data['math'] + $data['arab'] +
                            $data['history'];
                        echo $sum ;
                        ?>
            </td>
            <td><strong>مجموع الدرجات</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="center">
                        <?
                        $all=500 ;
                        $sum= $data['geo'] + $data['snum'] +
                            $data['math'] + $data['arab'] +
                            $data['history'];
                        $av=$sum/$all*100 ;
                        echo $av."%" ;
                        ?>
            </td>
            <td><strong>
                    النسبة المئوية
                </strong></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</tr>
</div>
        <?
    }
};
```

The full code link is:

http://www.mediafire.com/?2d4yzdjiym0

Comment: whats the value of $ss? since -1 is not empty

Comment: *(sidenote)* You should never trust user supplied params and add them to a SQL query unsanitized. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Your code is open for sql injection. You cannot pass parameters coming from the user directly into a sql query - use intval() or mysql_real_escape_string() on your params (intval for numbers, m_r_s_e for strings).

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['ss'])` give you?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (!isset($ss)) {
    echo "please write your search words";
}
```

instead of

```
if (empty($ss)) {
    echo "please write your search words";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to write

if (!isset($ss)) { echo "please write your search words"; }

Comment: yes i tried your code but The message that appears to me You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: this is the link for my full html php sql code
plzzz help

http://www.mediafire.com/?2d4yzdjiym0

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that $ss [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)? i.e. there is a POST variable with the name ss. you could test it with.

```
if (empty($ss) || !isset($ss)) {
    echo "please write your search words";
}
```

or test for it when you read in the post var

```
if ((!isset($_POST["ss"]) || (!is_numeric($_POST["ss"])))
{
    $ss = 0;//empty considers 0 as been empty
}
else
{
    $ss = $_POST["ss"];
}
```

ss looks to be a number too, so checking if it is numeric using is_numeric will help stop SQL errors, if for some reason it is not.

Comment: The message that appears to me
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: this may be due to you using $ss in the line $sql2=("SELECT * FROM student WHERE snum = $ss"); that comes before you check, if you replace the line $ss = $_POST["ss"]; with my second code sample does it sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the condition to

```
if(empty($_POST['ss'])){ ... }
```

and continue using $_POST['ss'] instead of $ss.

BTW Always use error_reporting(E_ALL) when developing.

Answer (score 0):

$sql=("SELECT * FROM student WHERE snum = $ss ");

Remove the brackets in the variables ($sql1 and $sql2) that have your query

It should be

$sql="SELECT * FROM student WHERE snum = $ss ";

I think that's why its telling you that you have an error near ...